# Display all sheet name with pandas rd.sheet_name not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

how to display all sheets name after read the excel.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
rd = pd.read_excel(r'xx.xlsx',sheet_name=0)
rd.sheet_name
```

Error message
*AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sheet_name'*

Comment: you should pass `sheet_names=None`, in which case you get `list(rd.keys())` for all the sheet names. Or use `ExcelFile` to get `.sheet_names`.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply!. I just fixed sheet_name  =None; however I got AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'sheet_name'; I don't understand why. Also i seems rd i got is a dictionary, correct?

Comment: Please read my other comment. I didn't say you should do `rd.sheet_name`...

Comment: Thank you! I got it now. Getting a list of sheet name by using keys.